# Canadian Ph.D. for a master of engineering science degree holder without transcript

Tags: phd, graduate-school, application, canada, transcript-of-records

I am **master of engineering science** graduate from Malaysia and here, the M.Sc. doesn't have any course work so it is pretty much like a 2 years Ph.D. thus I don't have any transcript or what-so-ever, only my publications, thesis and graduation letter. I want to know if it is acceptable to apply in Canadian universities without having any masters degree transcript or grading. Unfortunately the university graduate office is not willing to answer my question unless I pay the application fee and wait for 12 weeks.

P.S: I also have talked with a supervisor (in Uottawa) and he has already stated that he is willing to supervise me.

Comment: It is probably up to the school you apply to whether they will accept that. However, on your side, it should be sufficient to submit an explanatory note about this or to ask that your old institution produces one for you.

Comment: I see. I have a confirmation letter from my university stating that my masters study doesn't have any transcript. should upload that in the transcripts section while registering in the university website?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be a good idea.